# after ubuntu upgrade to 9.10: video playback is all green/blue tinted

Tags: video, ubuntu-9.10, upgrade

I just upgraded from ubutnu 9.04 to 9.10, and everything was working fine before the upgrade but now when ever I play a file in a video player everything has a blue/green tint. Its like my video went into Smurf mode! for some reason flash based video is still fine, ex. hulu/youtube both play just fine.

Comment: Frustrating! After upgrading to nVidia's drivers, my video playback started to show with green tints. Adjustments made with nVidia's X Server vidoe settings would correct the problem but only for the current video. The next video would revert to green. Removing nVidia's software helped, but I had to sacrifice the visual effects.

Comment: In totem Menu>Edit>Preferences:Display Just put the hue slider all the way to the left ;) That should remove all the green and blue hue Cheers, Ivo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, seems that the HUE is has been set to zero.

> Open totem
>   Menu:Edit->Preferences:Display [Reset
>   to defaults] Button

This adjusted everything for me, vlc, mplayer etc.

Comment: If you click the little star under the voting buttons on the question, it will add this question to your favorites.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this issue could be the use of the NVIDIA closed source driver; since this bug hasn't been addressed yet, here's a quick fix for when you use Totem:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, and then run this command:

   ```
   gstreamer-properties
   ```

   That should open up the "Multimedia System Selector" window.
2. Click on the "Video" tab and select "Custom" from the "Plugin" drop down menu.
3. Add the following line inside the "Pipeline" text box and just close it after:

   ```
   videobalance hue=-1 ! autovideosink
   ```
4. Quit Totem and reopen it for the changes to take effect.

Reference: http://www.junauza.com/2010/03/fix-blue-and-green-tinted-video-problem.html